# How to customize the preview button in Jahia CMS

Tags: java, content-management-system

I want to customize the jahia CMS Preview button,(which shown in Edit mode) what I need is whenever I click on preview button to see how our web page looks it open in the same tab but I need it should be open in new tab previous one is remain as in edit mode I have tried through different tutorials but couldn't find any solution regarding that.
your helpful view are appreciable.

Comment: You might want to add what you have tried so far (preferably code) and also browsing through the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) page might give you some ideas on what else to add.

Comment: Hi Qben, 

Thanks for showing interest in this  Actually I'm newbie in Jahia and try to customize the the functionality of that I didn't get the clue to from where should I start by the I have taken the source of jahia from following url http://subversion.jahia.org/svn/jahia_community_dev